# Kozsul Simplicial Complex a Cone

Tags: commutative-algebra, simplicial-complex, monomial-ideals, betti-numbers

I'm really not understanding the idea of the (upper) Koszul simplicial complex: For a monomial ideal $I$ and a degree $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{N}^n$, define the upper simplicial Koszul complex as $$K^{\mathbf{b}}(I)=\{\text{square free vectors }\tau \mid \mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{b}-\tau}\in I\}.$$
I need to show that this is a cone when $\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{b}}$ is not the lcm of some of the minimal monomial generators of $I$.

I tried to go about induction on the number of generators, but I wasn't sure what to do in the inductive step.

Answer (score 1):

[For convenience of notations, I will drop all the bolds.]

Presumably you are meant to also assume that $x^b\in I$ (otherwise $K^b(I)$ is empty).  Now let $x^a$ the the lcm of all the minimal monomial generators of $I$ which divide $x^b$.  By hypothesis, $a<b$; let $i$ be such that $a_i<b_i$.  Now observe that if $\tau\in K^b(I)$ and $\tau_i=0$, then $\tau'\in K^b(I)$ as well, where $\tau'$ is $\tau$ modified to have $\tau_i=1$.  Indeed, if $x^c$ is any minimal monomial generator of $I$ which divides $x^{b-\tau}$, then $c_i\leq a_i<b_i=b_i-\tau_i$ and so $c\leq b-\tau'$ and $x^c$ still divides $x^{b-\tau'}$.  In other words, $i$ can be added to any simplex of $K^b(I)$ to get another simplex; this says exactly that $K^b(I)$ is a cone with vertex $i$.

Comment: Since $0\in K^\mathbf{b}(I)$ as $x^\mathbf{b}\in I$, then can we say that $K^\mathbf{b}(I)$ can be considered as a cone with vertex $i$ for any $i$ with $a_i<b_i$?

Comment: $K^b(I)$ can be considered as a cone with vertex $i$ for any $i$ with $a_i<b_i$.  I don't know what that has to do with $0\in K^b(I)$, though.  (In fact, we should _not_ include $0$ in $K^b(I)$, since a simplicial complex is supposed to contain only nonempty sets.  That is, the definition of $K^b(I)$ should be modified to require $\tau$ to also be nonzero.)